# Angular Two Way Data Binding Not Working While Using HTTP

Tags: angularjs, mvvm, angularjs-scope, xmlhttprequest

I am using *ControllerAs* in angular with *ui.router*, I have an API in PHP when I call the API and set the scope variable by vm approach for templates then it works accordingly and when I want to delete some record set 
and update the *vm.servers* variable again then template not change according to the newly updated object.

```
function serverController( server, $state, $rootScope, $scope)
{
    var vm  = this;

    vm.delete = function(server_id) {
        vm.loader = false;
        server.delete('server/' + server_id)
            .then(
            function(response){
                if(response.status === 200 && !response.data.status) {
                    alert(response.data.message);

                } else if(response.status === 200 && response.data.status){
                    server.setRootScope().then(
                        function(){
                            vm.servers = $rootScope.servers;
                            $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
                        }
                    );

                }

            }, function(response) {
                if(response.status === 401) {
                    $state.go('login');
                }
            }
        );
    };


    if($rootScope.servers == undefined) {
        server.get('server')
            .then(
            function (response) {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    vm.servers = response.data;
                    $rootScope.servers = {};
                    angular.forEach(response.data, function (val) {
                        if('running' === val.status) {
                            val['serverState'] = true;
                        } else {
                            val['serverState'] = false;
                        }
                        $rootScope.servers[val.id] = val;
                    });
                }
            },
            function (response) {
                if (response.status === 401) {
                    $state.go('login');
                }
            });
    } else {
        vm.servers = $rootScope.servers;
    }
}
```

Template File.

```
<table class="table movietable" width="70%" border="1">
    <tr ng-repeat="server in serverModel.servers">
        <td width="85%">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Server Label: </b> {{server.label}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Status: {{server.status}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Created At: {{server.created_at}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I look your code. I found a problem that,

- You are not updating the **vm.servers** with
  the **response data**. As the values in **$rootScope.servers** might
  be older. So with every delete function call you will have to either update the **$rootScope.servers** or **vm.servers** with new data.

> I have create a small demo from your code, hope it will help you
>   identify the problem. In this demo I have first load the data in table
>   after this, on a button click deleting the record by id and updating
>   the **vm.servers**.

***My Controller***

```
.controller('Controller',['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    var vm =this;
    vm.customer = {
      name: 'Naomi',
      address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
    };

    vm.delete = function(server_id) { 
    vm.loader = false;

    // added some value to $rootScope.servers or you can update it with response data. This is where you will need to update your logic.
    $rootScope.servers = [
                            {   id: 1,   
                                name: 'Naomi1',   
                                address: '1600 Amphitheatre1' 
                            },
                            {   
                                id: 2,   
                                name: 'Naomi2',   
                                address: '1600 Amphitheatre2' 
                            }
                          ];  

    angular.forEach($rootScope.servers, function(value,key) {   
        if(value.id == server_id) { 
          $rootScope.servers.splice(key,1); 
        }
    });    

    console.log($rootScope.servers); 

    //Here I have assign new $rootScope.servers.
    vm.servers = $rootScope.servers;

    };

    var val = {};
    vm.init = function() {
            vm.servers = [{
                          id: 1,
                          name: 'Naomi1',
                          address: '1600 Amphitheatre1'
                        },{
                          id: 2,
                          name: 'Naomi2',
                          address: '1600 Amphitheatre2'
                        }];
            $rootScope.servers = {};
            val['serverState'] = true;
            $rootScope.servers[val.id] = val;
        }

    vm.init();

  }])
```

***index.html***

```
<div ng-controller="Controller as vm">
  <table class="table movietable" width="70%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="85%">
            <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="server in vm.servers">
                    <td><b>Server Label: </b> {{server.name}}</td>
                    <td>Status: {{server.address}}</td>
                    <td><button ng-click="vm.delete(server.id);">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**Hope this will help you !**

Cheers,
Jimmy

Comment: thank you James for you quick help, unfortunately i found that issue after the post. Thanks once again for your help.